# how to use regex replace to replace special character?

Tags: regex, dataframe, pyspark, regular-language

I am trying to replace "\" into \ using regex replace but not getting the proper solution. Want to remove the double quotes which is coming around . Can you please help me how to do this?

Example:

```
"\""warfarin was discontinued 3 days ago and xarelto was started when the INR was 2.7, and now the INR is 5.8, should Xarelto be continued or stopped?"
```

In result:

```
\"warfarin was discontinued 3 days ago and xarelto was started when the INR was 2.7, and now the INR is 5.8, should Xarelto be continued or stopped?"
```

Comment: is your problem solved already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
re.sub(r'"\\"', r'\\', text)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the respond. I am still facing the same problem. i used this - df = df.withColumn('QSTN', regexp_replace(col('QSTN'), '"\\"', '\\'))

Comment: for saving dataframe i am using -
df.repartition(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').mode('overwrite').save(output_path, escape='\"', sep='|',header='True',nullValue=None)

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution below:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, '"\\""warfarin was discontinued 3 days ago and xarelto was started when the INR was 2.7, and now the INR is 5.8, should Xarelto be continued or stopped?"')
], ("ID","textVal"))

import pandas as pd
from  pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 200)

df2 = df.withColumn('textVal', regexp_replace(col('textVal'), '\\"\\\\\"', '\\\\')) 
df2.toPandas()


ID  textVal
0   1   \"warfarin was discontinued 3 days ago and xarelto was started when the INR was 2.7, and now the INR is 5.8, should Xarelto be continued or stopped?"
```

Hope it helps!